# SQL 2016 The server was not found or was not accessible

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have that problem i cannot connect to SQL Server.
I get this error:

> Cannot connect to (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB. A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured
>   to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces,
>   error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Error occurred
>   during LocalDB instance startup: unable to create the SQL Server
>   process. ) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1983577844)

I have looked all over the internet, but all of them are solutions that don't work for me, they show something like you just need to connect to your server the right way, and then make a user login.
But how can I do that if I can't get into my server or database.

I can't get any further than this picture


[image]

I even tried through **Services** that some fix it through, or **SQL Server Configuration Manager** but I don't have any **SQL Server Services**.

As you can see on this picture


[image]

Btw it's saying there is no elements to show.

I have no idea to what I can do now.

Comment: Is this a fresh install?

Comment: You are trying to connect to a LocalDB instance on your local machine. LocalDB is an *Express* feature. Have you installed it?

Comment: Are you trying to access a database on your PC?  Try to replace `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` with `localhost\MSSQLLocalDB`